# CSS - How to prevent ul/ol li's second row of text from going further left than the first line?

Tags: html, css

I have a few lists on my webpages that look like this:

```
        > lorem
    ipsum
```

And I want them to look like this:

```
        > lorem
          ipsum
```

If you could even help me how to properly phrase the question I am after I would much appreciate it.

Comment: padding-left is your friend. You shouldn't need to bother with display: block, lists are already block-level elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

list-style-position is the CSS attribute you want, in particular setting it to "outside" - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#list-style

The w3 descriptions are confusing for the outside but the key is that inside places the marker as the first inline item in the content.

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisvenus/uQNPk/2/ has an example showing the results for inside and outside.

I believe that "outside" is usually the default which leads me to believe that you may have something in your stylesheet overriding this explicitly or possibly you are using some kind of reset stylesheet that has different defaults than you want.

Simply put the following should sort you out assuming no overriding from other stylesheet elements:

```
ul, ol
{
        list-style-position: outside;
}
```

You may also need to fiddle with the left margin to make sure your bullets don't hit something you don't want them to...

Comment: I am using the meyerweb css reset tool ( http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/  ) at the beginning of my css, perhaps that is the problem? I tried adding list-style-position: outside; (as it indeed seems like the right thing to do) but it changed nothing. So, I will investigate further. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can always try `list-style-position: outside !important;` as a sledgehammer approach to seeing if it helps. There is a chance that you have selectors with higher specificity that are overriding this one. Also you can try using your browser of choices css debugging. Firebug in firefox for example allows you to inspect what styles are being applied to an element and which stylesheet they are in. This should help you figure out if that is being overridden by something else.

Comment: Darn, tried that (!important) as well with no luck unfortunately. As I assume you are correct and it is external circumstances preventing me from doing so, I will mark you right. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

make it block, set padding, > insert with :before pseudo element :)

Comment: That is what I have done. If you see my above comment, I am using ( http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ ) so perhaps that is overriding something?